# error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_set<>' 'std::_Hashtable<>'

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

i got this error when i compile a program of my colleague, i searched several questions, it seems that the customized construe has not been initialized explicitly, but i am not sure, can some one experienced make your comments on this? That would be much grateful. Thanks in advance.

**error: use of deleted function**
‘std::unordered_set
<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = std::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Hash = std::hashstd::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Pred = std::equal_tostd::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Alloc = std::allocatorstd::filesystem::__cxx11::path]’
**std::unordered_set seen;**
**note: ‘std::unordered_set**<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = std::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Hash = std::hashstd::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Pred = std::equal_tostd::filesystem::__cxx11::path; _Alloc = std::allocatorstd::filesystem::__cxx11::path]’ **is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
unordered_set() = default;**

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code giving this compiler error. And in the future make sure to tag your C++ questions as C++, or nobody will find them. That's likely the reason why your question never got any answers. I've fixed the tags now. I assumed that by "GNU" you actually meant the gcc compiler.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for offering the help. The problem was solved last week by a colleague, it the version of GNU used on my pc.  When GNU version is newer than 12 use std::unordered_set instead of std::set. I will close this question.